# MongoDB return empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch info from my mongodb database but it keeps returning an empty object. I've used exactly same for fetching info from a collection called "users" and it works but not with anything else.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

var url = 'mongodb://test:test@124.355.99.268:27017/admin'; 

mongoose.connect(url); 

var userPBData = new Schema ({ 
   _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
    email: String, 
    password: String, 
    token: String, 
    name: String, 
    phone: String 
}); 

var UserPB = mongoose.model('user_pb', userPBData); 


UserPB.find( function(err, rows){ 
  if(err) { 
    console.log(err); 
  }else{ 
    console.log(rows); 
  } 
})
```

The database document inside "user_pb:

```
 { 
    "_id":"5ab6815820568524b570f818", 
    "email":"test@test.se", 
    "password":"dac2cc2b9bfc297f2ecebe3bc98a0d248", 
    "token":"6c4c10d6e2c1067faa3ff8aad0d8542b3a5e55f805bab397b18ca16b8f986a0c4", 
    "name":"Test", 
    "phone":"har ej" 
}
```

The console output:

```
[]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Check this section of the documentation. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find

Comment: No search criteria. First argument in UserPB.find() must be object with criteria eg UserPB.find({}) // finds all

Comment: `UserPB.find({}, (err, result) => { console.log(results); });`

Answer (score 0):

```
UserPB.find( function(err, rows){ 
  if(err) { 
    console.log(err); 
  }else{ 
    console.log(rows); 
  } 
})
```

first argument for query should be a selector. then you should put call back.

```
UserPB.find({}, function(err, rows){ 
  if(err) { 
    console.log(err); 
  }else{ 
    console.log(rows); 
  } 
})
```